# AffineTransform translation is not keeping image centered when zooming

Tags: java, swing, zooming, scale, affinetransform

The code opens a pdf and renders a page as a `bufferedImage`. The `paintComponent()` of my JPanel is overridden to use an `AffineTransform` to scale the `bufferedImage` and `drawRenderedImage()`.

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);

    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g.create();
    
    int w = this.getWidth();
    int h = this.getHeight();

    AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();

    at.translate(w/2, h/2);
    at.scale(scale, scale);
    at.translate(-w/2, -h/2);

    g2.drawRenderedImage(image, at);
    g2.dispose();
}
```

This is my first time using any sort of graphics, so it has been confusing and frustrating. I tried implementing the scale:

```
int w = (int)(this.getWidth()*this.scale);
int h = (int)(this.getHeight()*this.scale);
```

I've tried implementing the image sizes:

```
int imageWidth = this.image.getWidth();
int imageHeight = this.image.getHeight();

double x = (w-imageWidth*this.scale);
double y = (h-imageHeight*this.scale);
```

The previous try came from the tutorial I was using to learn how to make a zooming method. I've researched for some hours now and tried several different methods, but absolutely nothing has worked so far. I've had a few near successes where the movement is less dramatic until zoomed in far (how I currently have it is one). On the other hand, these tend to cut off the pdf and fail after zooming in enough.

Edit: This is my current paint component:

```
@Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g.create();
        
        int w = getWidth();
        int h = getHeight();

        int imageWidth = this.image.getWidth();
        int imageHeight = this.image.getHeight();


        AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();

        

        at.translate(w/2, h/2);

        at.scale(scale, scale);

        at.translate(-imageWidth/2, -imageHeight/2);

        g2.drawImage(image, at, null);

        g2.dispose();
    }
```

Comment: (1-) *I'm not sure how I would center the image.* - what do you mean??? Did you not test the code I provided??? The image is centered. Resize the frame and the image will remain centered. I posted complete code that you can copy/paste/compile and test. How does it NOT do what you are asking. The code you posted tells us nothing. How to you expect us to test that code? The rendered image is irrelevant to your stated question. The file chooser is irrelevant. First understand the basics of centering an image and THEN make changes to your code.

Comment: @camickr Please calm down, there's no need to be so rude. First, I'm still learning and came here because I don't know this stuff. I spent time researching after you mentioned centering the image and I couldn't find anything helpful. I did actually even copy and paste it, and it didn't work. I also just posted what I could fathom would be relevant code, and I don't know what else I could provide. Do you want my 14MB folder? I'm self-taught and came here for help understanding this and it's rude of you to demean me for it.

Comment: We are NOT here to debug your code. We are here to help provide information on solving a task. You were given an [mre] showing how to center an image. The code works for me or I would NOT have posted a complete example. *it didn't work.* - does not describe the problem. Post the code that you tested and include an image of the result. *I also just posted what I could fathom would be relevant code* - and I took the time to explain what relevant code means. You need to learn to simply the problem.

Comment: You have stated multiple time you are a beginner and I have taken the time to give advice on how to problem solve by simplifying the problem. We are not interested in your 14MB folder. I have showed you how to "center an image", using 20 lines of code. You need to understand Swing basics first before working on a larger project.

Comment: Saying you're not here to debug my code is reasonable. I apologize; however, I don't understand why you're being so antagonistic. I also realize that I did have it centered and even had it exactly like your code. The way you phrased it made me feel as though I was missing something. As for pictures, it won't let me put any. I can describe that when I start zooming in on the bottom right, the view can move all the way to the top left. When I said "it didn't work" I meant your code had no effect at all to the issue I was having.

Comment: I also originally included all of the relevant code that I knew, my graphics2d in my custom jpanel. the only other relevant part you could see that I did not include was me instantiating the class. You told me I didn't provide enough, so I gave you more. I knew it had no relevance to the question, but I guessed maybe there was more I missed. I also do understand the basics of swing quite well. My program is fully functional save two bugs, the zooming being one of them. Finally, it doesn't sound like you caught on, but the part about my folder was sarcasm.

Comment: I am not being antagonistic. You still don't realize that you have NOT properly described the problem or provided a proper [mre] so we can see the problem. You state - *when I start zooming in on the bottom right, the view can move all the way to the top left.* - I have no idea what that means.  The posted code attempts to zoom the entire image, so I don't know what zooming in on the "bottom right" means. Unless you can show this behaviour with an [mre] there is not much more we can do.

Comment: You can't post an image put you can upload the image and a link will be included with your question. We can then edit your question to display the image.

Answer (score 0):

```
at.translate(-w/2, -h/2);
```

Looks like the above translate should be based on the size of the image, not the panel.

Below is some code I found somewhere a long time ago:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.imageio.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import java.awt.image.*;

public class RotateAndScale extends JPanel
{
    private Image image;

    public RotateAndScale(Image image)
    {
        this.image = image;
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
         super.paintComponent(g);

         // create the transform, note that the transformations happen
         // in reversed order (so check them backwards)
         AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();

         // 4. translate it to the center of the component
         at.translate(getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2);

         // 3. do the actual rotation
         at.rotate(Math.toRadians(45));

         // 2. scale the image
         at.scale(0.5, 0.5);

         // 1. translate the object to rotate around the center
         at.translate(-image.getWidth(this) / 2, -image.getHeight(this) / 2);

         // draw the image
         Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g.create();
         g2.drawImage(image, at, null);
         g2.dispose();

         // continue drawing other stuff (non-transformed)
         //...
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        try
        {
            BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File("splash.gif"));

            JFrame frame = new JFrame("SSCCE");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.add( new RotateAndScale(image));
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setSize(400, 400);
            frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
            frame.setVisible( true );
        }
        catch(Exception e) { System.out.println(e); }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater( () -> createAndShowGUI() );
    }
}
```

You can just remove the rotation if you don't need it.

Comment: I just tried that and it didn't work. I can zoom in on the bottom right corner and end up at the top right.

Comment: @Ozakriid Is the image centered when you run the posted code? It is when I test the code. If it doesn't do what you want then your verbal description of the problem is not clear. Post your [mre] showing how you use the posted code. We can't guess what you are doing.

Comment: I'm not sure how I would center the image. I'm brand new to graphics in general and I haven't read anything that explained that. I added as much of my code to my question that I thought was relevant as I could.